# Scraping web pages with Python vs PHP?

Tags: php, python

I have been doing some research into web scraping and noticed it seems to be done mainly using Python, is there any benefit of using a Python based solutions over PHP, are there performance issues and so forth?

Comment: In short: it's subjective.

Comment: Agree with @amal, it's subjective. Python (that I love, to be honest) was primarily used as a glue language, not for Web related stuff, so there's a long history of 3rd party modules and especially string analysis. For performance, you could use gevent and greenlet to run quite easily some concurrent web scraping without doing some heavy modifications of your code base - but this is some kind of advanced usage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, I would go with python, because of its excellent string handling capabilities compared to PHP. Also there are a lot of cool libraries that python has , that make Scraping web pages a bliss.

Some libraries you should check out are :

[Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup)

[Scrappy](http://scrapy.org/%E2%80%8E)

I have personally used BeautifulSoup and its simple and really powerful.

Checkout this piece of code from their documentation :

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.icc-ccs.org/prc/piracyreport.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for incident in soup('td', width="90%"):
    where, linebreak, what = incident.contents[:3]
    print where.strip()
    print what.strip()
    print
```

Comment: A solution shouldn't be marked as valid if it's based only by opinions or just because someone shared a library for make basic scraping activities easier.
Why i prefer PHP instead of Python?
Because with php you can use regular expressions, decode/encode json data, and moreover you can easily save scraped data into db, local files and so on.
Php can be used within CLI like python and i can't see differences.

Answer (score 1):

The real test, in my opinion, would be to see how **scalable** each method is and how they handle memory management once I start scraping say the entire Wikipedia collection. I could be wrong here but from what I’ve read so far, **Python is the tool of choice for such heavy processing tasks**. FOR eg `SCRAPY` *it have its own scraping functions and peculiarly designed for this job only*.

Either way, I think I’ll go with Python only ;)

Answer (score 1):

`python` is best and [`SCRAPY`](http://www.scrapy.org/) is an open-souce which makes your work easier within a day or two.